# What directory should my Apache folders be in to transfer to vagrant box?

Tags: vagrant, packer

I am trying to use a post shell script to copy the directory of an apache website into a vagrant box using packer but Im not sure what directory I should put the directory that contains all the files for apache. I keep running into this error:

```
ubuntu-vanilla-16011-server: cp -r bootstrap-website/ ~/var/www/html/
ubuntu-vanilla-16011-server: cp: cannot stat 'bootstrap-website/': No such file or directory
==> ubuntu-vanilla-16011-server: Unregistering and deleting virtual machine...
==> ubuntu-vanilla-16011-server: Deleting output directory...

Build 'ubuntu-vanilla-16011-server' errored: Script exited with non-zero exit status: 1
==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> ubuntu-vanilla-16011-server: Script exited with non-zero exit status: 1
==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

Here is my post install script:

```
 #!/bin/bash 
set -e
set -v


# http://superuser.com/questions/196848/how-do-i-create-an-administrator-user-on-ubuntu
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on
# This line assumes the user you created in the preseed directory is vagrant
echo "vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/init-users
sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/init-users


# Installing vagrant keys
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://raw.github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub'
sudo mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.ssh
sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.ssh
cat ./vagrant.pub >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys

apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2 
apt-get install -y php
if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
  rm -rf /var/www
  ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
fi
cp -r bootstrap-website/ ~/var/www/html/
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any file on the host machine doesn't automatically get transfered to the guest. You need to use [file provisioner](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/file.html) to upload `bootstrap-website`.

Comment: Thanks so much so should the directory that I want to upload into the box be in the same directory as the json files?

Comment: Yes, it should.